# Why do I get implicit declaration of function 'open64'/'openat'/'openat64' warning on Ubuntu?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

gcc 4.8.2

```
#define __USE_FILE_OFFSET64
#define __USE_LARGEFILE64
#include <fcntl.h>

int
main(void) {
    int fd = open64("/", O_RDONLY);
    return 0;
}
```

Then gcc's output is 'warning: implicit declaration of function ‘open64’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]'. But in fcntl.h:

```
#ifndef __USE_FILE_OFFSET64
extern int open (const char *__file, int __oflag, ...) __nonnull ((1));
#else
# ifdef __REDIRECT
extern int __REDIRECT (open, (const char *__file, int __oflag, ...), open64)
     __nonnull ((1));
# else
#  define open open64
# endif
#endif
#ifdef __USE_LARGEFILE64
extern int open64 (const char *__file, int __oflag, ...) __nonnull ((1));
#endif
```

Function openat/openat64 has the same problem even though #define __USE_ATFILE is added. I have no idea what happened to these.

Comment: did you forget to `#include <sys/types.h>` and `#include <sys/stat.h>`?

Comment: @mch :I tried but it didn't work

Comment: `fcntl.h` includes `features.h`, which `undef`s all your defines.

Comment: Just use `open` (with `-D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1`)

Comment: @keltar : I read the features.h and added the _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE, then the open64 has no warning. But there is still warning about openat after adding #define _ATFILE_SOURCE. Do you know how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : do you know how to use openat? #define _ATFILE_SOURCE didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: @GuangmuZhu I cannot reproduce that, `openat` and `openat64` are here. Can you edit the question to add full example for your new problem?

Comment: @keltar : Sorry for this. I didn't know `_ATFILE_SOURCE` so I used the `linux/fcntl.h` which is replaced with `fcntl.h` now. All are fine, thank you! @BasileStarynkevitch

Answer (score 5):

Correct define flag for LARGEFILE64 is `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE`. All your `__USE_*` manipulations are undone by `features.h`.